# how to get a value out of a class's init function python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

I am working with `tkinter`'s class-based structure and I need to get a value of text input. How do I do that?

Here is the relevant code:

```py
#GUI
class PseudostreamWidget(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kw)
        self.targetIP = tk.Entry(self.Ipconfig)
        self.targetIP.configure(background='black', font='{Lato} 12 {}', foreground='white', highlightbackground='black')
        self.targetIP.configure(highlightcolor='black', justify='left', relief='raised')
        _text_ = '''Friend's Public IP Here'''
        self.targetIP.delete('0', 'end')
        self.targetIP.insert('0', _text_)
        self.targetIP.grid(column='1', row='0')
        #
        #
        #
        target_ip = self.targetIP
        #
        #
```

How do I get it to print `target_ip` outside the class?

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()  
    widget = PseudostreamWidget(root)
    widget.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    root.mainloop()

print(target_ip)
```

Comment: Just use `widget.targetIP` since you assign `self.targetIP` (and `widget` is `self` in the constructor).

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `tkinter get value from Entry widget` into a search engine?

Comment: @AKX I don't think OP knows how to use event driven programming :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class PseudostreamWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, callback=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.targetIP = tk.Entry(self, fg="white", justify="left",
                                 relief="raised", highlightbackground="black",
                                 highlightcolor="black", bg="black",
                                 insertbackground="white", font=("Lato", 12))
        # self.targetIP.delete(0, "end") # No need for this
        self.targetIP.insert(0, "Friend's Public IP Here")
        self.targetIP.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.targetIP.bind("<Return>", callback)


def submit_data(event=None):
    print("You typed in:", widget.targetIP.get())

root = tk.Tk()
widget = PseudostreamWidget(root, callback=submit_data)
widget.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

To use it just write something inside the entry and press the `Enter` key on your keyboard.

It passes in a function (`submit_data`) and binds to it.

Comment: hey, thanks this works, but I am just curious, what should I read about to get this?? This is my first time working with class-based structure of Tkinter, also, I am gonna accept this as the best answer once I integrate this with my code, which is proving to be more difficult than I anticipated, is it okay, if I try for a few hours and then I if I don't get it can I ask you for help?

Comment: @VardhanMahajan You should read/experiment with [event driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Basically the code shouldn't flow top to bottom (most of the time). Functions should be called when the user does an action like click/press a keyboard button. In this case the user chooses when to press the `Enter` key. That is why I defined a function to handle it.

Comment: @VardhanMahajan You can always ask for my help :D. That is why I am on this website.

Comment: ohh, dude, thank you so much, btw, I am just gonna accept your answer, thank you for your time and effort really appreciate it!

Comment: dude, how are you so nice, I dont get it. most people on stackoverflow are so nice and helpful and you are beyond that, I dont get it, but thanks for the help and the sentiment. you are a very good human! when I get better I promise to pass the knowledge and help other people. meanwhile I will read up on event based programming